# Ajax response getting too slow

Tags: javascript, ajax, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I facing a problem when getting the data from servlet using ajax. The response is getting too slow. Anyone suggest how to get the data faster? Here below is my code

```
function loaduedate(outlet,c) {    
    var d1 = new Date();    
    var d = new Date();    
    $.ajax({    
       url: 'GetDueDate',    
       type: 'post',    
       data: {out: outlet, opt: c},    
       dataType: 'json',    
       success: function(data) {    
           alert(JSON.stringify(data));               
           $("#txtduedateno").val(data.duedays);       

       var numdays = $('#txtduedateno').val();    
       d.setDate(d.getDate() + parseInt(numdays));    
       var weekday = new Array(7);    
       weekday[0] = "Sunday";    
       weekday[1] = "Monday";    
       weekday[2] = "Tuesday";    
       weekday[3] = "Wednesday";    
       weekday[4] = "Thursday";    
       weekday[5] = "Friday";    
       weekday[6] = "Saturday";    
       if (weekday[d.getDay()] === "Sunday") {    
           d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);    
       }    
       }    
    });      

}    

function changeTextBoxForItem(Id1, Id2) {
    $(Id1).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 112) {
            e.preventDefault();
            loaduedate(outletid,1);//loaduedate function calling from here             
        }
});
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that your response times get longer and longer?  First response is fine, and subsequent responses get slower and slower?  If so this is not an ajax thing, this is your server handler ( 'GetDueDate' )

Comment: Yes sir exactly. Thanks for your's info. I will check with it

Comment: How is **changeTextBoxForItem()** called?

Comment: changeTextBoxForItem() is called when event occurs <input type="text" id="txtItem" class="cl" style="width: 200px" onkeypress="changeTextBoxForItem(this, txtQty)" />